# Bootstrap scrollspy not working when links contains parentheses

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I just found out that the scrollspy from twitter bootstrap was not working when I had a link name that contains parentheses.

After some research, it seems that it is due to the jQuery selector, and the parenthesis would need to be escaped.

I am wondering if there is an elegant solution to to workaround or if I should get rid of the parentheses in my links ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end getting rid of the parenthesis is the best solution, since parenthesis don't comply with HTML4 rules for id attribute, as found on this question:
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)